# Automatically labeling points appearing in graphics

Tags: graphics, labeling

I'm trying to automatically label my points `pl` with my text `plt` and plot this to `Graphics[]`.

So far this is my concept:

```
plt = Table["P" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, l}]`
```

which returns `{P1, P2, P3}`

```
pl = Table[{xl[[i]] + 10, yl[[i]] + 10}, {i, 1, l}]`
```

which returns

> ```
> {{3736.81, -2313.76}, {2317.05, 3315.64}, {-5640.83, -19923.8}}
> ```

According to the documentaion `Text` needs an expression and coordinatess, thus is `Text[expr, coords]`.

However,

```
Graphics[{Text[Table[{plt[[i]], pl[[i]]}, {i, 1, l}]]}]
```

yields

```
{{"P1", {3736.81, -2313.76}}, {"P2", {2317.05, 3315.64}}, {"P3", {-5640.83, -19923.8}}}
```

which is not a result `Graphics[]` can plot.

Has anyone an idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: try `Graphics[{Table[Text[plt[[i]], pl[[i]]], {i, 1, l}]}]`?

Comment: or `Graphics[{Text @@@ Table[{plt[[i]], pl[[i]]}, {i, 1, l}]}]`

Comment: see also [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)  (e.g. `Graphics@Thread@Text[plt, pl]`) and [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)  (e.g. `Graphics@MapThread[Text]@{plt, pl}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is following:

```
pt=RandomReal[{-5,5},{10,2}];
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.025], Point@pt, Blue, Text[ToString@#, # + {0.25, 0.25}] & /@ pt}]
```

[image]

The term `{0.25,0.25}` defines the shift of the label relatively the point.